# How to get trailing slash from root_path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I've got the whole app running in under www.example.com/myapp/.

I've got the typical root setup in my app using scope as in:

```
scope "/myapp/" do
  root :to => "home#index"
end
```

I'd like to use the `root_path` method.  However, it omits the final trailing slash and this interferes with routing in my web server.  I could certainly fuss with the web server routing, but I'd really just like rails to give me a trailing slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

root_path is deprecated: http://apidock.com/rails/Rails/Configuration/root_path . I'm pretty sure you want something like the examples provided here http://joneslee85.wordpress.com/2010/05/27/the-dilemma-of-rails-root-vs-rails_root-complex/, look at Rails.root.